# Training parts of a neural net with independent optimizers

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Consider a neural net that consists of two parts:

```py
from torch import nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, x_dim, out_dim, h_dim=42):
        super().__init__()
        self.part1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(x_dim, h_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            ...
        )
        self.part2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(h_dim, h_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            ...
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.part1(x)
        x = self.part2(x)
        return x
```

In principle, would it be possible to train it's model parameters with multiple optimizers - one for each part, such that

```py
model = Model(...)
opt1 = Adam(model.part1.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
opt2 = Adam(model.part2.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

The rationale is that if we assume that `model.part1` is a pre-trained network. When we train the composite `Model` for a downstream task, we would like to adjust the parameters of `part1` to a lower degree than `part2`, because we expect the pre-trained parameters of `part1` to be already close to a minimum.
Would such an approach work, or are there other ways of implementing that logic?

Comment: "Would such an approach work" - have you tried it? What would the training data look like for each part? What would the training data be for the entire model?

Comment: You should use optimizer groups instead of separate optimizers if both sub-components of your model are using the same optimization algorithm.

Comment: The training is an iterative process and needs and each parameter needs an initial value. If you want to train two sub-modules separately, you need to freeze the first model parameters and train the second one then train the second one while the first model parameters are frozen.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is

```py
opt = Adam([
        {'params': model.part1.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-5},
        {'params': model.part2.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3))}, ...)
```

Where `...` are keyword arguments to  default to when a per-group parameter is unspecified.